# How to implement EF Core ValueComparer for List<TModel> JSON converter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I stumbled upon the [compiled models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#compiled-models) paragraph of the MSDN article about [Advanced Performance Topics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics) regarding Entity Framework Core and wanted to try it out. When running the `dotnet ef dbcontext optimize` command in the command line, I get the following error:

> The property 'FooModel.BarProperty' has a value comparer configured using a ValueComparer instance. Instead, create types that inherit from ValueConverter and ValueComparer and use 'HasConversion=<ConverterType, ComparerType=>()' or 'HasConversion(Type converterType, Type comparerType)' to configure the value converter and comparer.

The converter for `BarProperty` is currently configured in the overwritten `OnModelCreating` method of my `DbContext` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FooModel>()
            .Property(x => x.BarProperty)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<BarModel>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                    new ValueComparer<List<BarModel>>(
                        (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                        c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                        c => c.ToList()));
```

This code is responsible for saving (serializing / deserializing) some related objects as JSON in a column and works like a charm. But I am struggeling to move / translate this inline-code to custom [`ValueConverter<TModel,TProvider>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.valueconverter-2?view=efcore-6.0) and [`ValueComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.valuecomparer-1?view=efcore-6.0) implementations. Another reason why I want to prevent the inline-code is that it is very repetetive and used multiple times in the exact way for different properties.

I don't even know if I need to implement the generic `ValueConverter<List<BarModel>, string>` or just `ValueConverter`. Neither do I know which generic types I have to define (especially `TProvider` is confusing me).

Thanks in advance for your precious help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how I solved it.

In my DbContext:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
    configurationBuilder.Properties<List<FooModel>>().HaveConversion<FooModelCoverter, FooModelComparer>();
}
```

Comparer:

```
internal class FooModelComparer : ValueComparer<List<FooModel>>
{
    public FooModelComparer()
        : base((c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
                c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
                c => c.ToList())
    { }
}
```

Converter:

```
internal class FooModelCoverter : ValueConverter<List<FooModel>, string>
{
    public FooModelCoverter() : 
        base(v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
             v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FooModel>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null), 
             null)
    { }
}
```